# What does .jpg?t= mean?

Tags: php, html, jpeg

this [webcam image](https://www.webcam-4insiders.com/current/big/105-Webcam-Riederalp-Wetter.jpg?t=1512496926) has **?t=1512496926** append to it. What does it mean? Is it the time? Does it do anything at all?

[image]

Comment: Yes, It's the time

Comment: yeah, it means you don't have the source code for it.

Comment: it prevents from being cached

Comment: In what format though? Seconds, minutes? Can I just append stuff to files? Where can I read more on this? What is it called?

Comment: Yes, that's a UNIX timestamp for right around now-ish. http://www.convert-unix-time.com/?t=1512496926

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it's a "cache buster".  By appending the current time (or any changing value) to the URL, browsers always re-request the content from the server instead of relying on their local cache.  Because the request has technically changed.

The server-side code (if there even is any) can simply ignore this value.  And it likely is doing so.  The intent is simply to ensure that users always get the latest version of the information.  For a webcam image like this one, it ensures that the users aren't seeing an old image.

Comment: Thanks for this in-depth explanation :)